# Server Error while saving panda dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, permissions, ubuntu-18.04

part of my python script is as below

```
panda_dataframe.to_csv("myfile.csv")
```

The code is working fine in my Dev System.

I have deployed it in EC2 - Ubuntu. The above statement return Server Error (500)

I have also tried with

```
panda_dataframe.to_csv("/usr/share/myfile.csv")
```

But the same error.

Error.log has the below error.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/myfile.csv'
```

I have tried with setting the below permisions

```
sudo setfacl -m u:www-data:rw /var/www/sitefolder/myfile.csv
sudo setfacl -m g:www-data:rw /var/www/sitefolder/myfile.csv
```

Guide me what is the permission I have to assign to write the dataframe into a csv file

Comment: Apparently you dont have write permission, this is not a pandas related problem, more about your ubuntu server settings. Try writing it to the `tmp` folder: `panda_dataframe.to_csv("/tmp/myfile.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory is `/usr/share`, and saving/deleting/copy/move actions in `/user` directory requires `sudo` privileges. so first check you user directory by executing `echo $HOME`. say the result is `/home/amir`. now save you data frame as:

```
panda_dataframe.to_csv("/home/amir/myfile.csv")
```